# Foreign key issue in mysql (error 1005)

Tags: mysql

I have attempted to create the following tables:

Customer:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(customer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      surname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
                      forename VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
                      DOB TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
                      phone_no VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                      email_address VARCHAR(30),
                      postcode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
                      PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

When I attempt to create the 'Booking' table afterwards, I get an error

> "ERROR 1005(HY000): can't create table 'Test.Booking' (errno:150)"

I checked the error online and found out that it was relating to the Foreign key connection that I attempted to make between the tables; which I will give below.

Booking:

```
CREATE TABLE Booking (booking_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                      customer_id INT NOT NULL,
                      staying_from TIMESTAMP,
                      staying_until TIMESTAMP,
                      cost INT,
                      PRIMARY KEY(booking_id),
                      FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(customer_id)
                      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [`FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> Foreign keys definitions are subject to the following conditions:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar internal data types inside `InnoDB` so that they can be compared without a type conversion. *The size and sign of integer types must be the same.* The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

In `Customer` you have `INT UNSIGNED` whereas in `Booking` you have `INT`.