# Error 1005 in MySQL upon execution of ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, database

This is a long question please read through. I have listed some of the links I have referred, but I have read all the suggestion thrown up while posting this question. This is not a duplicate question as marked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341481/unable-to-figure-out-the-cause-for-error-1005-in-mysql-database.

I've been trying to write a small MySQL database, which contains two tables role and user defined as follows:

role

```
CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `roleid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `role_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `permission` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roleid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `roleid` (`roleid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `role_name` (`role_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

user

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uname` (`uname`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `password` (`password`),
  KEY `rid` (`rid`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rid`) REFERENCES `role` (`roleid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

So now when I issue the `ALTER TABLE 'user' DROP FOREIGN KEY;`

I get an error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'parth.#sql-418_24' (errno: 150)
```

parth is the name of the database.

I've consulted following discussions:

- [Error 1005 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873929/error-1005-in-mysql)
- [Error 1005 in MySQL (from foreign key syntax?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157015/error-1005-in-mysql-from-foreign-key-syntax)
- [Foreign Key in MySQL : ERROR 1005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706416/foreign-key-in-mysql-error-1005)
- [Foreign key issue in mysql (error 1005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671480/foreign-key-issue-in-mysql-error-1005)
- [Special Characters in MySQL Table Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443050/special-characters-in-mysql-table-name)
- MySQL Reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

The `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` gave the following output regarding the above situation:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
150710 18:20:35 Error in foreign key constraint of table parth/#sql-418_24:
foreign key:
Syntax error close to:
```

Please help me figure this out. Thanks.

The table parth/#sql-418_24 generated automatically when I executed the ALTER TABLE command. According to the reference manual ALTER TABLE works by copying the contents of the original table into a temporary table, which in this case is #sql-418_24 which is then renamed to the name of the table as specified in the schema. So it doesn't seem like a problem with special characters in table name. Please help.

MySql Version  5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
operating system Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this ...

```
ALTER TABLE `user`  DROP FOREIGN KEY `user_ibfk_1`;
```

you are supposed to drop a constraint, here the constraint is named `user_ibfk_1`

Comment: ALTER TABLE table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY constraint_name is the statement used to drop a foreign key. You have to specify a constraint name in this case. If you omit it, MySQL generates a constraint name for you.

Comment: @abhishek would you pkease mark it as the correct answer ... and you are welcome. Happy to help.